# DataPower B2BGW with HA pollers

Tags: high-availability, b2b, ibm-datapower

In DP XB62, a B2B Persistence store can be setup to run in HA configuration with a primary node with writeaccess and a standby/slave node with only read access. This is tightly connected with Virtual IPs and standby control. This works fine for inbound connections (HTTP for instance), but how can I put pollers into active/standby control?

I.e. MQ,SFTP and FTP polling Front side handlers should be deactivated when the machine is in standby mode (and the B2B persistence store is in standby mode).

Can this be achieved in XB62 firmware 6.0.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, it can't...
As the stand-by control of the DataPower boxes isn't a "real" cluster it won't deactivate the passive box, merely remove the IP address from it.
The pollers will still poll on the stand-by box and there is unfortunately no way around that.

Some customers who wants all processing to be done on one box I normally setup a "poller MPGW" that has the backside set to the VIP. That way any poller who polls data will send to the "active" box and the processing will happen there.
This is most convenient if you only want to monitor one B2B Transaction Viewer for example.

I have been testing a few scripts as well where I enable/disable the FSH depending on events sent at fail-over but I have found that there are a few too many events to monitor for that to be a "safe" approach...